# Flutter FilePicker is not giving back the file

Tags: android, flutter, asynchronous, filepicker

I have a problem and can't get why it happens.
When I pick a file with the FilePicker seems like the await never end and the code can't get over the "await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles"

This is the code:

```
  Future<void> _addFile([String name, String uri]) async {
    PlatformFile file;
    FilePickerResult result;
    if (name != null && uri != null) {
      addAttachment(name, uri);
      return;
    } else {
      globals.logHelper.info("SELECTING THE FILE:");
      try {
        result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: FileType.any
        );
        globals.logHelper.info("RESULT ================" + result.toString());
      } catch (e){
        globals.logHelper.error(e);
      }
      if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
        file = result.files.first;
        globals.logHelper.info("FILE FOUND: " + file.name);
        _addFile(file.name, file.path);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

This function is called inside a button:

```
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await _addFile();
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.file_present, size: 75))),
```

And, after I've chosen a file, if I try to pick a new file I get this error:

```
I/flutter (17157): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(already_active, File picker is already active, null, null)
E/flutter (17157): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (17157): #0      _AttachmentListViewWidgetState._addFile (package:smtu/widgets/AttachmentListViewWidget.dart:142:33)
E/flutter (17157): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17157): #1      _AttachmentListViewWidgetState._addAttachment.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:smtu/widgets/AttachmentListViewWidget.dart:110:29)
E/flutter (17157): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17157):
```

I've tried to put a Try Catch to see if any error is throw, but none happens.
I've searched online for a solution but seems like my code should be okay.

I would like to get the File, to be more precise I need only the filePath.

I mostly need it for Android.

Edit1: addAttachment code:

```
void addAttachment(String name, String uri) {
    globals.logHelper.info("Adding a new attachment");
    setState(() {
      _attachments.add(Attachment(name, uri));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your addAttachment method?